# Why Official django foundation is removing 'syncdb' command in django 1.9 release?

Tags: python, django

Releasing in near future [django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9) clearly states that syncdb command will be removed . what will be the pros and cons of this ?

Comment: You should probably ask the Django project themselves if you want to know why they've decided to do this.

Comment: some of the people on SOF are from the developing team of django. I thought maybe they could answer this. I already sent an email to django community about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a case of pros or cons really, the syncdb command was made redundant in [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/) as a third party library known as "South" used for database migrations was merged into the Django core, Djangos built in migrations now use "migrate" instead of "syncdb". "syncdb" was deprecated in 1.7, left in only to support old projects that had not transitioned to using the new migrations.

Comment: but wasn't migrate command only for model migrations ?
P.S.-  still using south , django 1.6

Comment: yes...model migrations == syncing the database

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/ . here it says Migrations are Django’s way of propagating changes you make to your models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) , not creating tables but updating them.

Comment: Pre-1.7 you have two commands, `syncdb` that would create the database tables and `migrate` from south that would do schema migrations. From 1.7 onwards you have the `makemigrations` command which creates an initial schema migration for an app- basically what syncdb did- and then migrate runs all of these migrations in the same way  south did so there is no need for syncdb

Answer (score 5):

Your question is answered in [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/).

> Prior to version 1.7, Django only supported adding new models to the
>   database; it was not possible to alter or remove existing models via
>   the syncdb command (the predecessor to migrate).
>
> Third-party tools, most notably South, provided support for these
>   additional types of change, but it was considered important enough
>   that support was brought into core Django.

Since `migrate` is a superset of `syncdb`, there is no reason to keep on supporting the `syncdb` command in releases beyond 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Django is now able to use migrations, which transforms your models into python database schema code which makes it compatible with all types of databases. And so instead of having to add your new tables using raw sql you can simply type

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

Which will do everything for you